Flutter Web: After reload webpage from browser the browser back and forward button do not work
I created a web application using flutter and to manage state I used GetX. Now I describe my issues that I'm facing, Firstly I am using GetX default navigation route in my project.
Suppose, I have two screens "Screen A" and "Screen B" and I navigate from Screen A to Screen B. After Navigating to Screen B I reload this page from browser reload button and the page is reloaded. When I  try to back to the Screen A after reloading browser back button doesn't work. I initialize route this way....
class AppPages {
  AppPages._();

  static const INITIAL = Routes.SPLASH;

  static final routes = [
    /// ----------------------------- splash screen ----------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.SPLASH,
      page: () => const SplashView(),
      binding: SplashBinding(),
    ),

    /// ----------------------------- login screen -----------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.LOGIN,
      page: () => const LoginView(),
      binding: LoginBinding(),
    ),

    /// ----------------------------- forget password screen --------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.FORGET_PASSWORD,
      page: () => const ForgetPasswordView(),
      binding: ForgetPasswordBinding(),
    ),

    /// ------------------------------ new password screen ----------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.NEW_PASSWORD,
      page: () => const NewPasswordView(),
      binding: NewPasswordBinding(),
    ),

    /// ------------------------------ registration screen -----------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.REGISTRATION,
      page: () => const RegistrationView(),
      binding: RegistrationBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- home screen ----------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.HOME,
      page: () => const HomeView(),
      binding: HomeBinding(),
    ),

    /// ----------------------- message screen ----------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.MESSAGE,
      page: () => const MessageView(),
      binding: MessageBinding(),
    ),

    /// ------------------------ create post screen -----------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.CREATE_POST,
      page: () => const CreatePostView(),
      binding: CreatePostBinding(),
    ),

    /// ------------------------- notification screen ---------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.NOTIFICATION,
      page: () => const NotificationView(),
      binding: NotificationBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- profile screen --------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.PROFILE,
      page: () => const ProfileView(),
      binding: ProfileBinding(),
    ),

    /// --------------------------- favorite list screen ----------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.FAVORITE_LIST,
      page: () => const FavoriteListView(),
      binding: FavoriteListBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- call history screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.CALL_HISTORY,
      page: () => const CallHistoryView(),
      binding: CallHistoryBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- purchase history screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.PURCHASE_HISTORY,
      page: () => const PurchaseHistoryView(),
      binding: PurchaseHistoryBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- face verification screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.FACE_VERIFICATION,
      page: () => const FaceVerificationView(),
      binding: FaceVerificationBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- about us screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.ABOUT_US,
      page: () => const AboutUsView(),
      binding: AboutUsBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- edit profile screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.EDIT_PROFILE,
      page: () => const EditProfileView(),
      binding: EditProfileBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- account settings screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.ACCOUNT_SETTINGS,
      page: () => const AccountSettingsView(),
      binding: AccountSettingsBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- notification settings screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS,
      page: () => const NotificationSettingsView(),
      binding: NotificationSettingsBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- privacy policy screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.PRIVACY_POLICY,
      page: () => const PrivacyPolicyView(),
      binding: PrivacyPolicyBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- ilu point screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.ILU_POINT,
      page: () => const IluPointView(),
      binding: IluPointBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- otp verification screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.OTP_VERIFICATION,
      page: () => const OtpVerificationView(),
      binding: OtpVerificationBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- details profile screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.DETAILS_PROFILE,
      page: () => const DetailsProfileView(),
      binding: DetailsProfileBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- My Timeline screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.MY_TIMELINE,
      page: () => const MyTimelineView(),
      binding: MyTimelineBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- call history screen -------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.BLOCK_LIST,
      page: () => const BlockListView(),
      binding: BlockListBinding(),
    ),

    /// -------------------------- chat screen ---------------------------------
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.CHAT,
      page: () => const ChatView(),
      binding: ChatBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.REWARD_HISTORY,
      page: () => const RewardHistoryView(),
      binding: RewardHistoryBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.WITHDRAW_HISTORY,
      page: () => const WithdrawHistoryView(),
      binding: WithdrawHistoryBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.WITHDRAW_REWARD_POINT,
      page: () => const WithdrawRewardPointView(),
      binding: WithdrawRewardPointBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.BANK_WITHDRAW,
      page: () => const BankWithdrawView(),
      binding: BankWithdrawBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.BKASH_WITHDRAW,
      page: () => const BkashWithdrawView(),
      binding: BkashWithdrawBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.NAGAD_WITHDRAW,
      page: () => const NagadWithdrawView(),
      binding: NagadWithdrawBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.REGISTRATION_OTP,
      page: () => const RegistrationOtpView(),
      binding: RegistrationOtpBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.INVOICE_DETAILS,
      page: () => const InvoiceDetailsView(),
      binding: InvoiceDetailsBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.DETAILS_IMAGES,
      page: () => const DetailsImagesView(),
      binding: DetailsImagesBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.HELP_AND_SUPPORT,
      page: () => const HelpAndSupportView(),
      binding: HelpAndSupportBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS,
      page: () => const TermsAndConditionsView(),
      binding: TermsAndConditionsBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.AUDIO_CALL,
      page: () => const AudioCallView(),
      binding: AudioCallBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: _Paths.EDIT_POST,
      page: () => const EditPostView(),
      binding: EditPostBinding(),
    ),
  ];
}


I don't find any exact solution for this.
